# Is it valid to use "time ago in words" for Schema.org Date/DateTime properties?

Tags: schema.org, date-format

I have a message board site and wanted to incorporate some schema to its posts. One of the main attributes for posts is the time in which they're creating in.

With that being said I came across the [`dateCreated`](https://schema.org/dateCreated) property. The one issue I'm facing in the formatting requirements. The expected type is either `Date` or `DateTime`. For UX purposes I was interested in displaying the post date in time ago in words. So instead of:

```
October 21, 2015, 7:28 AM
```

I would do something like:

```
5 minutes ago
```

Would I still be able to do something like the latter since it isn't exactly in date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the `DateTime` as property value (for the structured data / for machines), while displaying a human-readable variant.

Microdata and RDFa will take the `time` element’s `datetime` attribute value as property value, not the element content:

```html
<!-- Microdata -->
<time itemprop="dateCreated" datetime="2015-10-21T07:28:00">5 minutes ago</time>

<!-- RDFa -->
<time property="dateCreated" datetime="2015-10-21T07:28:00">5 minutes ago</time>
```